# MATLAB - FM Modulation

Tags: matlab

I am trying to Frequency modulate a sine signal using Matlab. I have written the following code for the same:

```
clc;
Fc = 5000; %Carrier Signal
fs = 20000; %Sampling Rate
t = 0:0.00001:0.002;
freqdev = 50; %Frequency Deviation
x = sin(2*pi*1000*t);
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(t,x);
y = fmmod(x,Fc,fs,freqdev,0);
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(t,y);
z = fmdemod(y,Fc,fs,freqdev,0);
subplot(3,1,3);
plot(t,z);
```

The above code gives me the following output:

[image]

- The first plot shows the modulating (sine) signal.
- The second plot shows the FM modulated signal.
- The third plot shows the demodulated signal.

But the second and third plots doesn't look like a FM modulated signal and demodulated signals respectively. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Just wondering why you chose `fs = 20000` and yet `t = 0:0.00001:0.002` (which corresponds to `fs = 100000`) ?  See what happens when you choose `t = [0:Fs-1]'/Fs; % Sampling times` as per the matlab manual page for `fmmod`.

Comment: @PeterK. Are questions about debugging MATLAB code on-topic on dsp.SE?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I believe so. I tend not to flag such things, depending on the community to flag them first. If I "flag" it as closed, it gets closed immediately... which may lead to too much "shooting from the hip."

Comment: As Peter K points out in his comment, the problem is actually caused by the way you are choosing your sample times.  If you modify line 4 of your code as follows: `t = 0:0.00001:0.002; t=t(1:end-1);`.

Unfortunately I can't give any insight as to why this is the case.  It probably has something to do with the way Matlab implements the `fmmod` function, since from a purely analog perspective, taking samples from `t=0` to `t=Fs` should be no different from taking samples from `t=0` to `t=Fs-1`.